# How to solve not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected

Tags: java, android, tabs, swipeview

I'm trying to create `navigation drawer` in my app. In one of my `navigation drawer item`, `View` , I want it to has 2 `tabs` with `swipe view` feature. I get error `Viewview is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected`.

**MainActivity** // for navigation drawer item

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment=new Information();
                break;
            case 1:

                fragment=new Claims1();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putLong("ab",WorkDetailsTable.ab);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment=new ViewView();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit(); 

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewView**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class ViewView extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = {"Information", "receipt"};


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View View1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewview1, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) View1.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });


        BuildList();
        return View1;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**TabsFragmentPagerAdapter**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(index) {
            case 0:
                return new UpdatePage2();
            case 1:
                return new Receipt();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

}
```

**Error**

> Error:(50, 47) error: incompatible types: android.app.ActionBar cannot
>   be converted to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message is clear. Your `ViewView` class implements `TabListener` but doesn't contain implementation of `onTabReselected`. You have an implementation of `onTabReselected` in the anonymous class instance implementing `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()`, which you define in your `onCreateView` method.

The question is do you need `ViewView` to implement `TabListener`. If you do, add the methods required by `TabListener` directly to `ViewView`. If not, remove the `implements ActionBar.TabListener` clause.

Comment: ya, I need. Did you mean  add `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()` in my `onCreateView` method?

Comment: How to add TabListener  directly to Viewview ?

Comment: @Tony `ViewView` doesn't contain an implementation of `onTabReselcted`. It must contain such an implementation if you wish it to implement `TabListener`.

Comment: @Tony put `onTabReselected` outside your `onCreateView` method.

Comment: After `onPageSelected`, everything  move outside or just `onTabReselected`?

Comment: @Tony That depends on whether the other methods are also required by the `TabListener` interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95795/discussion-between-tony-and-eran).